# C# - Using regex with if statements

Tags: c#, .net, windows, regex

I have some code that checks a fields input against a regex, although for some reason (no matter what I put in the field, it returns flase. Is there something I have missed?

```
private void textBox5_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    String AllowedChars = @"^a-zA-Z0-9.$";
    if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox5.Text, AllowedChars))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Valid");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your reg exp is wrong. It looks to me like it's saying "allow anything except a-zA-Z0-9."

Comment: "I know I'll use Regex to solve my problem!" Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex makes no sense to me. This one would (notice the square brackets used for defining an alphabet):

```
String AllowedChars = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
```

Answer (score 6):

What you want is to group those characters and allow 0 or more:

```
@"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$"
```

Otherwise, what you posted allows "a-zA-Z0-9" and one more character *only*.

Answer (score 5):

Probably incorrect regex. Maybe you meant this:

```
String AllowedChars = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
```

This would allow any number (including none) of alphanumeric chars. I have removed the period (which matches any character) because it does not make much sense in this context.

Comment: The period may have been intended to be a literal period character rather than a metacharacter (perhaps "www.example.com" is a valid input), especially considering the variable name of `AllowedChars`.  In that case, it should be included within the square brackets.